# Editable Listbox of textboxes in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

My aim is to be able to add/ edit/delete items to a listbox. I have created a listbox of textboxes in the following way. I am able to display data but I am not able to edit data. Can someone help me modify the code so that I can achieve this functionality.

```
<ListBox Name="lbDemoBox" ItemsSource="{Binding testList}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" SelectionChanged="lbDemoBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}"  KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Here is the code behind

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    private string focusedString { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LayoutRoot.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }

    private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter && (Keyboard.Modifiers & (ModifierKeys.Shift)) == ModifierKeys.Shift)
        {
            (lbDemoBox.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<string>).Add(string.Empty);
        }



    }

    private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
        {
            int index = (lbDemoBox.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<string>).IndexOf(focusedString);

            (lbDemoBox.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<string>).RemoveAt(index);

        }
    }

    private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        focusedString = (sender as TextBox).Text;
    }

    private void lbDemoBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> testList
    {
        get { return new ObservableCollection<string> { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3" }; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by edit the data, you want two-way binding?

Comment: Yes, I want two way binding and the moment I set Mode=TwoWay, I get an exception "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=YourProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Dimitry, Path=. because I am binding to a List<string> and the moment I set mode = twoway I get a "Value does not fall within the expected range" exception